# Arrancando con stack mern, como relacionar categorías con articulos? (Relación de uno a muchos)

Tags: javascript, nodejs, reactjs, mongodb, express

Estoy iniciando en el mundo de JS mas precisamente por el stack mern...

Ya realice con node y express todo el back (REST API) y almacene todo con mongodb

Ahora estoy con React en el front, me tiene mariado, la cuestión es que estoy haciendo un blog de cero, pero no logro entender como relacionar los artículos por los id de las categorías del blog para que muestre los artículos de dicha categoría, logre listar, crear, eliminar (me falta editar) gracias a axios esstoy trayendo todo del back...

Esa relación la tengo que hacer desde back o en el front hago todas las relaciones?

Este es el código donde muestro todos los artículos (posts)

```
state = {
    posts: []
}

componentDidMount(){
    this.getPosts();
}

async getPosts(){
    const res = await axios.get('http://localhost:4000/api/posts'); 
    this.setState({posts: res.data});
}
```

Desde ya muchas gracias por leerme

Comment: Las relaciones entre entidades van en tu motor de bases de datos pues ahí se almacena la información y de ahí la extraerá, por otro lado creo erraste la elección pues mongo es una base de datos NO relacional luego entonces si ocupas ese detalle por qué no volteaste antes a SQL ?

Comment: la parte del back esta de 10 (por ahora jaja) el tema es el front, y como decis, y no lo pense lo de mongo, pero alguna manera de relacionar debe a ver??? desconozco, me metí en MERN por q es la misma curva de aprendizaje y quería aprender js

Comment: Pues como menciono mongo no está pensado para eso, por otro lado establecer esas relaciones no veo como tiene algo que ver con tu front que es la interfaz de tu sistema, donde solo se consume la información si como dices ya tienes el back entonces como tienes problemas con las relaciones pues ese es el primer punto que debiste cubrir

Comment: Claro, me tiene medio mareado literal el tema... entonces toda esa relación q no hice, la tengo q hacer en el back? y solo pintarla con react? algo asi seria ?

Answer (score 0):

Directamente Mongo no puede hacer relaciones, pero, a pesar de ello, puedes hacer perfectamente relaciones con `Schemas()` de mongoose en Nodejs, haciendo referencia a otras tablas (collecciones) con `type: ObjectId, ref: La_Colección_FK`.

Usualmente puedes hacer `populate()` (que es básicamente un Join y en lo trae como un SubDocument en el json) cuando tienes estas referencias en el modelo, pero cuando quieres obtener desde la Colección referenciada el Document que le hizo referencia, entonces populate() no sirve, dado que no tienes como saber ese id (según el modelo) a menos que guardes también en Documento referenciado una referencia a su padre, pero es contraproducente.

Lo que debes hacer en estos casos puntuales son consultas con `aggregate()` la cual te permite traer toda la base de datos si quieres, anidada la información como tu quieras y en la forma que quieras, claro que las funciones a utilizar tienen otro formato y al principio lo veras algo complejo, pero puedes hacer cosas increibles y consultas muy complejas que posiblemente con una relacional no podrías, todo gracias a la flexibilidad de mongo.